Screen changer doesn't work


I'm using KDE Plasma on Archlinux.
I can change, turn on and off screens from settings manually, and it works fine.
But when I use the shortcut to start this app, the app doesn't work, It seems to do nothing.
I start it with default preset Fn+F8


Do you Happen to be on a Laptop?  Is the Fn Key Blue or White?  If it's Blue, the Fn Key  performs the Blue Operation which is not F8 (this would do "nothing." It depends on the manufacturer as to what the Blue Functions are).   You only use the Fn key to emulate F(n) if it's white.  If you're only using Arch, turn off the need for the Fn Key altogether in your laptop's Settings/BIOS utility
